# Conditional Format for Shapes

Tags: excel, vba

follow my question:

I have a project in which I need some shapes to receive conditional formatting based on named cell values.

For this I followed the following reasoning:

I recorded a Macro to identify the encoding of the attribute I would like to change, after that I made its change inside the VBA editor by inserting the IF function and informing the desired formatting conditions.

However, when I run this macro the changes are not applied.

When following the execution of the line-by-line code, I noticed that the lines referring to the formatting of the attribute in question were being skipped. So I made a correction to the indentation, but even so the changes are not being applied. Would anyone have any idea how to solve?

```
    Sub Condiciona_Icon()


' ---------------------------- FORMATAÇÃO CONDICIONAL DE ÍCONE ------------

'
Sheets("Início").Select


    Range("A14").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("IconEtp1")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        If CP_1 = "Atrasado" Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf CP_1 = "Regular" Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        End If
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there anything assigned to `CP_1`? Otherwise it will probably fail both the `if` and the `elseif`and skip to `end if`

Comment: You may also want to [avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code

Comment: Yes Christofer, these cells are filled in another worksheet in the same workbook.

Comment: cybernetic.nomad I'll try it.

Comment: Are there only two possible values for CP_1 ?  Do you need an `Else` for other values?  Where is CP_1 declared and assigned a value?

Comment: These cells? Unless you tell it that `CP_1` is something specific, excel won't know what that variable is.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not fluent in english. I meant that.

Comment: Yes Tim Williams. CP_1 is declared in the worksheet itself and its value refers to a specific cell which in this case is the cell "E2" of the workshhet "Prazo" on the same woorkbook.

Comment: Guys I managed to solve. The error was in setting the value as friends said above. Follows the corrected code.

Comment: ```Sub Condiciona_Icon()

Dim CP1 As String


CP1 = Sheets("Prazos").Range("CP_1")


Sheets("Início").Select


    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("IconEtp1")).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        If CP1 = "Atrasado" Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        ElseIf CP1 = "Regular" Then
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(146, 208, 80)
        End If
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    Selection.ShapeRange.Line.Visible = msoFalse

End Sub```

Comment: If you want to use named ranges in your code you can reference them like `[namedRange]`. For you, it would be `[CP_1]`